# Cuando paso de Activity y establezco para que haga una animación de slide al cambiar de Activity se muestra la pantalla en negro - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android Studio y necesito que cuando yo presione un botón se cambie de Activty y vaya a otro y que cuando abra el segundo Activity este haga una animación de slide de izquierda a derecha. Pero el problema es que cuando yo cambio de Activity se muestra la pantalla en negro, sin la animación y tengo que apagar y prender la pantalla para que se vea el Activity necesitaría una forma de arreglarlo

**Codigo del segundo Activity OnCreate()**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apps_list);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
}
```

**slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <translate
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
      android:fromXDelta="100%p"
      android:toXDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

**slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <translate
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
      android:fromXDelta="0%p"
      android:toXDelta="-100%p">
   </translate>
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano y marco la respuesta que me sirvio

Comment: Que se te pone negro? =\ @joaquingiordano Agrega el código y el layour de la segunda Activity activity_apps_list.xml

Comment: se ve toda la pantalla en negro solo se muestra la barra de notificaciones. Y no entiendo a que te refieres porque el código esta en el create del segundo Activity

Comment: elimina   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out); del segundo Activity,  quien realiza la animación es la primer activity no es así?

Comment: En teoría ese es el código que realiza la animación y había leído que había que ponerlo en el segundo actvity

Comment: y si el  overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out); lo pongo en el botón que pasa del activity 1 al activity 2 pasa lo mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo solucione no se ni como pero lo solucione puse de código:

**Codigo del segundo Activity OnCreate()**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apps_list);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
}
```

**slide_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p">
    </translate>
```

**slide_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="100%p">
    </translate>
```

dejo esto por si alguien le pasaba lo mismo que lo intente